# How to import and use RobinHerbots' Inputmask in Aurelia

Tags: jquery, typescript, aurelia, jquery-inputmask, input-mask

I'm trying to use [RobinHerbots' Inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) in Aurelia but cannot seem to import it correctly.

I've come across people discussing using this plugin in Aurelia but I could not find specific documentation on how to do this.

After `npm i inputmask --save` this is what I have in my `aurelia.json`:

```
{
   "name": "inputmask",
   "path": "../node_modules/inputmask/dist",
   "main": "jquery.inputmask.bundle",
   "deps": [
      "jquery"
      ]
}
```

In my `package.json` I've declared `inputmask`.

```
"dependencies": {
//...
"inputmask": "^3.3.11",
//...
}
```

I see no errors running `au build`. However, when I import using ES6 I can't use any of its properties.

```
import Inputmask from "inputmask";

attached() {
     let im = new Inputmask('999-99-9999');
     let select = document.getElementById('social-security-number-field');
     im.mask(select);
}
```

Yields `Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: inputmask_1.default is not a constructor` and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

[Inputmask error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LYHF.jpg)

When I try using the `data-inputmask` attribute it does not work either.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="social-security-number-field" value.bind="ssn" data-inputmask="'mask': '999-99-9999'">
```

[Input is not successfully masked using data-inputmask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8efa.jpg)

Am I missing something? I have only had experience importing plugins that are expressly for Aurelia or state specifically that they can be used with Aurelia, so I could indeed be missing something vital.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `jquery.inputmask.bundle.js` bundle isn't very compatible. They bundled it with webpack. It doesn't have any default exports and probably only works with webpack.

Try importing the regular build outputs:

```
{
   "name": "inputmask",
   "path": "../node_modules/inputmask/dist/inputmask",
   "main": "inputmask",
   "deps": ["jquery"]
}
```

This will require the other dependencies which you may need to include in your `aurelia.json` as well, but you'll get a proper warning if that's the case.

#### Edit:

You should also change your import statement from:

`import inputmask from "inputmask"`;

to:

`import * as inputmask from "inputmask"`;

inputmask doesn't have a default export, which is why that import statement won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I tried your solution. There were no build errors but I am still getting `Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: inputmask_1.default is not a constructor` and `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` when I try to use Inputmask in the class, and this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of null` when I try to use the data-inputmask attribute.

Comment: @flea Oh sorry I just noticed I missed something, you should change `import inputmask from "inputmask";` to `import * as inputmask from "inputmask";`. Updated my answer.